# SocialSharing plugin not showing the FB , SMS icons on android

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-social-plugins, socialshare

I am using EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin and 'shareWithOptions' The plugin works on my Iphone . However, I don't see FB, SMS icon as an option on the share sheet when using the android device.. I see it on my Iphone

The apps are install on the android phone... Can you give me hints on how to debug this issue

Thanks